Не работает консольная GO игра на другой OS windows
Сделал небольшое консольное приложение на go, собрал его под свою ОС (linux mint) оно запускается и работет нормально, Но стоит мне собрать его под виндовс 10 оно не работает
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "bufio"
  "log"
  "math/rand"
  "os"
  "strconv"
  "time"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  i := 10

  fmt.Println("Game Guess Number!     (1 - 15)")
  fmt.Println("You have", i, "Attempts", "\n")

  for i = i; i > 0; i-- {
    seconds := time.Now().UnixNano()
    rand.Seed(seconds)

    target := float64(rand.Intn(15) + 1)
 
    fmt.Println("Attempt: " ,i)
    fmt.Print("Your guess: ", "\n")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    input = strings.TrimSpace(input)
    guess, err := strconv.ParseFloat(input, 64)
 
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error type is not a number")
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if guess == target {
      fmt.Println("You Won!!!", "\n")
      break
    } else if guess > target { 
      fmt.Println("Too High", "\n")
    } else if guess < target {
      fmt.Println("Too Low", "\n")
    }
}

  if i == 0 {
  fmt.Println("You lose :(", "\n")
  }

  fmt.Println("Game End")
}


wine GuessNumberGame.exe
0074:err:winediag:is_broken_driver Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
Game Guess Number!     (1 - 100)                                                              
You have 10 Attempts 

Attempt:  10
Your guess: 
2024/08/28 01:58:12 read /dev/stdin: input/output error

    ~/Документы/temps    main !1 ?1                                   01:58:12  ─╮
❯ 0034:err:winediag:is_broken_driver Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.






wine GuessNumberGame.exe
You have 10 Attempts
Attempt:  10
Your guess:
2024/08/28 02:12:13 read /dev/stdin: input/output error

Нужно перевести терминал в RawMode перед началом работы с ним.
